# Thread not stopping when it's supposed to

Tags: python

So I'm making a kind-of Minecraft hack client in python (I know there are many better languages to do this but please don't bully me about it), and I'm using threads for it to be able to run multiple hacks at once. And one of the features is autoGap (automatically eat Golden apples). Every second or so, it checks for low health. And it works after the first time. But even after it finishes eating and regenerating health it does not stop.
My code:

```py
    def autoGapCode(self):
        global currentdir
        findInv = imgRecognition()
        low = False
        imgList = ['hearts1', 'hearts2', 'hearts3', 'hearts4', 'hearts5', 'hearts6', 'hearts7']
        while True:
            for i in range(len(imgList)):
                imgSt = findInv.detectImage(str(currentdir)+'/img/'+imgList[i]+'.png')
                if imgSt is None:
                    t.sleep(0.3)
                    continue
                else:
                    low = True
                    break
        
            if low == True:
                pa.press('4')
                pa.mouseDown(button='right')
                t.sleep(3)
                pa.mouseUp(button='right')
                pa.press('1')
                low = False

   
    def autoGap(self):
        global threads
        self.autoGapThread = threading.Thread(target=self.autoGapCode)
        if self.autoGapStatus == False:
            self.autoGapStatus == True
            threads.addThread(self.autoGapThread)
        else:
            self.autoGapStatus = False
            self.autoGapThread.stop()
```

If you need the full code and/or the folder with all the images, comment with your request.
Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> As a preface, I've never coded anything like what you're describing and have limited experience with Python multi-threading. As such I can only offer advice on what I can assume to be the problem. Sorry. Hope it's useful advice anyway

From what I can see, your code is getting stuck in the `while True` loop.

The last line of the `for i in range(len(imgList))` loop beaks out of that loop, not the `while` loop. This means it then goes to the `if low == True` section, and once that's run or not, it goes back to the start of the `while True` loop, never getting a chance to break out of that loop.

What I think you're trying to do with the `t.sleep` is set the interval between checks which is why the thread never finishes. I would instead consider making the thread non-blocking (if it isn't already) or spawning a new process (or just running the process from the main thread if it's quick enough) every second or so. There may also be some function call made when the player's health changes you would be able to take advantage of.

---

I'd also like to put a few reccomendations for code here in case you want to use them. Instead of iterating `for i in range(len(imgList))` then using `imgList[i]` you could simply have (with the possible addition of [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) if you're using Python 3.6+)

```py
for i in ingList:
     imgSt = findInv.detectImage(f"{currentdir}/img/{i}.png")
```

Also, you can simplify `if low == True` to just `if low`